# Why my multiprocess PHP CLI command into docker work as single process?

Tags: php, docker, asynchronous

So, I made cli script using [async lib](https://github.com/spatie/async). As I understood right that lib creates child process for every task and executes them parallel. It works perfectly on my local environment.
But when I try to use it via docker container looks like my script work as a single-process (too slow) and from child processes, nothing gets into stdout. 
I am not an expert in docker and right now I really don't know where I need to look for.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you using a TS (thread safe) version of PHP in the docker container?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thread Safety is disabled

Comment: Parallelism will require it.

Comment: @MarkusZeller maybe I incorrectly expressed when wrote 'multiprocess'. Script executed in One process and then create several child processes. I think this happens within a single thread.